# easiest way to port an SDL-1.2-based game to iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdl

I have a SDL-1.2 based game and I want to port this to the iPhone so I want to ask about the easiest way. I am working on MacOSX and have already the iPhone SDK by Apple (so I guess the [iPhone Toolchain](http://www.saurik.com/id/4) is not the right thing for me as I am using MacOSX).

I know there is the [iphone-sdl-1-3](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-sdl-1-3/) project but I wonder if that is the only SDL port, i.e. I have no other choice to first port the game to SDL-1.3. Also, the project page is very inconcrete, there aren't really any instructions. Also their SVN is empty and there is no single documentation and/or wikipage. The only thing in this project is a simple testproject ZIP-file. I guess I have to fetch the official SDL-1.3 source from SVN and try to build that somehow. Is that right? Are there perhaps prebuild binaries which I can download somewhere?

I also have looked at other projects, for example [ScummVM](http://www.scummvm.org/). [It seems](http://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php/Compiling_ScummVM/iPhone) they are using the iPhone Toolchain to crossbuild it on Linux. But they are not really saying what SDL version they are using and how to link against it. [In their forum](http://forums.scummvm.org/viewtopic.php?t=4606) somebody stated that [iphone-mame-sdl](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-sdl-mame/) is used. Though it seems that this project is dead - at least the Google Code project is not accessible right now (returns a 403 error).

I have also seen [another question here on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597459/how-mature-is-sdl-for-iphone) about it (with the result to use SDL-1.3 SVN) - though it is already half a year old and I wonder if the situation has changed.

So, after all, what would be the easiest way for a SDL-1.2 based game? Where to get SDL from? SDL-1.2 or SDL-1.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get SDL from the svn. The easiest way would be to use the compatibility mode, so your 1.2 functions should work fine, but it will be much slower than using the new API.

Comment: Thanks, I'll just try that. I guess I have to compile a lib myself and distribute&link that with my app? Or statically link that?

Comment: Just want to note: When you build SDL-trunk from the provided Xcode project file for iPhone, it builds SDL as a static lib. I guess that answer also my other question about the best way how to link against it.