# Game engine for iPhone/Android

Tags: iphone, android, game-engine

Is it possible to do cross platform game engine for iphone and android. if its how can i do this. what are all thinks i need to study to do this.

Comment: There are many game engines that support both iPhone and Android. I suggest you pick one or two and experiment with them to which best meets your need. I have put together a large index of [mobile game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com) where you could use the filters to list all engines that support the platforms you are interested in.

Comment: jasonb: Just came back to thank you for putting that list together.

Answer (score 13):

Check out Cocos2d-x. It's completely free and open-source.

There is also http://www.appgamekit.com It's something I am interested in. It supports "Basic" as well as "C++".

I think that Marmalade is really powerful. I've messed around with it. And highly recommend it.

If you are only targeting Android and iOS for a 2D game, I would highly recommend Cocos2d-x. It's one of the most game-complete and free framework for C++ I've come across.

The advantage of using Cocos2d-x opposed to Marmalade is that most of the components of a game engine is written. You can prototype a game in less than a day. Cocos2d-x is also free.

I wrote my own game engine with Marmalade and it took no longer than a week (on and off work, of course).

The disadvantage of Cocos2d-x is obviously less variety of platform support.

If you're willing to spend a bit of money but also need the simplicity that Cocos2d-x offers. Check out http://appgamekit.com It's cheaper than Marmalade SDK and easier to use. It is also extensive via C++.

Deciding on what to use mainly depends on your constraints. I am currently using Cocos2d-x for an upcoming project scheduled to be released for iOS very soon.

Answer (score 8):

Check out *[Unity 3D](http://www.unity3d.com)*

Supports also PC, Mac, and others.

Comment: thz wernight, but actually i am trying to develop a game engine or a framework to develop 2d or 3d game for both iphone & android. plz help me for this.

Comment: In short you're trying to make something like Unity. HAHA. That's a pretty large project. Even huge if you mean to make it a general game engine. OpenGL should work on both. If you're looking for a middleware, you may try your luck with **SDL** (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597459/how-mature-is-sdl-for-iphone).

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at Shiva3D, it supports Windows, MacOS, Linux, iPhone, iPad, Android, Palm WebOS and Wii http://www.stonetrip.com/

Answer (score 4):

Just to weigh in with a biased alternative to the engines...

We just put out a new product which is a bit lower-level than a game engine.  It's called [BatteryTech](http://www.batterypoweredgames.com/batterytech) and it's a lightweight SDK that provides all of the Windows, iPhone, Android and Mac platform-abstraction services as the engines, but without requiring you to use an engine.  We develop custom engines (it's not that hard, really) for our games and figure others want to as well, so take a look if it seems like what you want.

Comment: Just FYI - BatteryTech SDK 2.0 and Engine are available at http://www.batterytechsdk.com and it's got awesome support for the core mobile platforms, nice OpenGL ES 2.0 based 3D rendering, Ouya support, etc.  Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that's cool. I'm glad Unity is finally starting to support Android.

For another one, take a look at Corona (for both Android and iPhone, thought it requires a Mac)
http://anscamobile.com/corona/

Answer (score 2):

A few more:

- [Marmalade](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com)
- [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com)
- [BatteryTech](http://www.batterypoweredgames.com/batterytech)

Marmalade and MoSync can target almost every platform and are very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Also there is another called "ethanon".
"https://github.com/asantee/ethanon"

For android,ios,windows,MacOsX,and blackberry playbook there is another called ["gameplay3d"](http://www.gameplay3d.org/)

Answer (score 1):

As one of the developers I will recommend Linderdaum Engine, it supports Windows, Android, MacOS http://www.linderdaum.com

Answer (score 1):

[V-Play](http://v-play.net/) (v-play.net) is a cross platform game engine based on Qt/QML  with many useful V-Play QML game components for handling multiple display resolutions & aspect ratios, animations, particles, physics, path finding and more. See their [API reference](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-group.html) for a full list of features and components.
V-Play also comes with ready-to-use [game templates](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-examples.html) for the most successful game genres like tower defense, platform games or puzzle games.

Answer (score 0):

[Moai](http://getmoai.com/) is free for smaller projects, and used by big studios as well. I run homebrew myself, but if I didn't I would probably use Moai myself as it looks very promising. They claim it ports to Mac, PC, iOS, Android and I think even Kindle Fire.