# Question about making games in C and transfering them cross platforms (from iphone to android)

Tags: iphone, android, c

I want to build games in C on iphone (I know C# and Java right now, but i can learn C).

I know Android can run on Native Dalvik, can I easily transfer a game from iphone to Android for example..and to JTME.

I have books on android that explain about game development, but none of them actually talk about developing a game in C (or native dalvik)..

So the question is how easy it is to transfer a game written in C across platforms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can use C/C++ on both iPhone and Android for a game's "game" part, however the device related parts should be done with different code, might in Objective C on iPhone or Java on android.

You should try some open source game engine that supports both the platforms, you may check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996793/game-engine-for-iphone-android).

Hope that could be helpful

Comment: so the answer might be using unity. What about using flash and actionscript and embedding it in any platform I want?

Comment: Unity uses C#, as far as I know. And Flash might have a efficient issue on mobile devices.

Comment: My current project uses [Unreal Engine](http://www.unrealengine.com/),  it works on PC, iPhone, Android, as well as many other platforms, however It might be too complicated for a new comer to C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Marmalade SDK    take a look here [**Marmalade SDK**](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you going to written games in basic 'C' language you can use it in android using NDK,
for reference check here,

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

but i don`t know whether same code can be used for iphone.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach, in my opinion, us to use C AND openGL code for the bulk of your work. C and opengl work on iphones, androids, and of course, macs and windows.

You will need some wrapper code for each platform. So objective-c for iphone, windows code for MS, and the android native toolkit wrapper code.

Once your app is started, all the "real" game coding in c and openGL will work on all the platforms